# How do I disable the Intellij "Enable Automatic Synchronization" warning that appears in the Java editor?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project that I imported into Intellij.  As libaries that are used by the project are changing, Intellij notifies me within the Java editor that "Some libraries have changed in the project.  This may have change..." followed by 2 clickable options "Synchronize Dependencies" and "Enable Automatic Synchronization".  Typically, I would "Enable Automatic Synchronization" but this particular project is no longer able to resolve any dependencies in the Java editor after I click "Enable Automatic Synchronization".  The problem is that this particular project does not follow typical Maven standards for proper pom structure.

I would ultimately like to be able to disable this message, but I can't find the preference to do so.  Does anyone know how to disable this message in Intellij?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more correct to just fix the pom?

Comment: In a typical project yes :).  The problem is that this project is one of many that are part of a global enterprise solution where all pom structure changes must be approved by an architect. "Fixing" the pom structure for this project has been rejected because of other potential impacts it has on the other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this setting (`Maven Import` in `Settings` | `Notifications`)?

[image: maven import]

Comment: My initial problem was caused by an incorrectly named environment variable for maven2.  Intellij 12 uses M2_HOME by default and I had MAVEN_HOME which is unconventional.  Your post was helpful because that was the next problem I encountered.  I would +1 your post if I wasn't a newb with only 6 rep points :)